GCP Edit Disk disabled and only "Loading ..." is shown
I have a disk on GCP which I want to edit, but the ui shows only a "Loading ..." tooltip on hoover and the Edit button is deactivated. See screenshot.
I executed the describe command and the status was Ready
gcloud  compute disks describe DISK_NAME --zone us-east1-d

Result:
..
    status: READY
..

And I have the privileges of:
compute.disks.addResourcePolicies, compute.disks.removeResourcePolicies, compute.disks.resize, compute.disks.setLabels and compute.disks.update 



If the disk is used by an instance, an additional privilege is required:
compute.instances.get

